# Is there a way to get the last crawl duration of all the content sources in SharePoint 2010 using power shell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, enterprise-search

Is there a way to get the last crawl duration of all the content sources in SharePoint 2010 using power shell?

i tried below script but it gave me an error.

```
   $results = @()

function Get-FormatedTimeSpan()
{
    param([TimeSpan]$TimeSpan)

    if($TimeSpan -and $TimeSpan -eq [TimeSpan]::MinValue -or $TimeSpan -eq [TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
    {
        $TimeSpan = [TimeSpan]::Zero
    }

    return [string]::Format( "{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", $TimeSpan.Days * 24 + $TimeSpan.Hours, $TimeSpan.Minutes, $TimeSpan.Seconds);
}
```

## enumerate all the search services in the farm

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | % {

    $searchService = $_
    $crawLog = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLog($searchService)

    # enumerate all the content sources for this search service
    $crawLog.GetCrawlStatisticsByContentSource() | % {

        $crawlStats = $_

        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "Search Service Application" = $searchService.Name;
            "Content Source Name"        = $crawlStats.ContentSourceName;
            "Last Crawl Duration"        = Get-FormatedTimeSpan -t $crawlStats.LastCrawlDuration
        }
    }
}

$results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sources = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application DEV"
ForEach ($source in $sources) {
    if ($source.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") {
        $time1 = ((Get-Date) - $source.CrawlStarted)
        $time1 =  Get-Date "$time1" -Format HH:mm:ss
        if($time1.Hours -ge 3 )
        {
            Write-Host $source.Name $time1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225136/how-to-get-the-current-crawl-duration-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/225153#225153). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!