# How to get the current crawl duration using powershell in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, search

I could able to get the name of active crawls, how to get the current crawl duration

From the below powershell script which i tried.

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application DEV" | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle")
{
    Write-Host $_.Name      

}
```

}

[image: Current crawl duration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration is not exposed, however the start date/time is available under the crawl source property "CrawlStarted". With this, we can use the Get-Date cmdlet to get the current date/time and subtract the CrawlStarted date/time to find the duration. The following PowerShell can be used to print the duration to the console.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$sources = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service"
ForEach ($source in $sources) {
    if ($source.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") {
        Write-Host ((Get-Date) - $source.CrawlStarted)
    }
}
```

To address your question of finding previous crawl logs and sending an alert if the crawl took over 3 hours, please try the script below. It will write an alert to the console if the last crawl for any content source took over 3 hours. Please modify to suit your exact requirements.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq "Search Service"
}
$sources = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $ssa
ForEach ($source in $sources) {
    $log = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLog $ssa
    $last = $log.GetCrawlHistory(1, $source.Id)[0]
    if ($last.CrawlDuration.Hours -ge 3) {
        Write-Host "Content Source $($source.Name): last crawl took over 3 hours!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldnt able to parse the final value to do a comparison like if the crawl duration is more than 3 hours send an alert.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you with code on how to achieve this alert.

Comment: $log = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLog $ssa
-- This line throws an error:

Comment: Whille this script wont work? 

$sources = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application DEV"
ForEach ($source in $sources) {
    if ($source.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") {
        $time1 = ((Get-Date) - $source.CrawlStarted)
        $time1 =  Get-Date "$time1" -Format HH:mm:ss
        if($time1.Hours -ge 3 )
        {
            Write-Host $source.Name $time1
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$sources = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application DEV"
ForEach ($source in $sources) {
    if ($source.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") {
        $time1 = ((Get-Date) - $source.CrawlStarted)
        $time1 =  Get-Date "$time1" -Format HH:mm:ss
        if($time1.Hours -ge 3 )
        {
            Write-Host $source.Name $time1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this question has been answered, I think this should be taken to a new question.